# Partial derivative problem: Need verification

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

> I need to solve the following partial derivative for a statistical mechanics problem I'm doing.
>   $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}[N \ln N - n \ln n - (N-n)\ln (N-n)] $$
>   I would just like to know if my solution is correct.

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}[N \ln N] & = 0 \\
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}[n \ln n] & = \ln n  +1 \\
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}[(N-n) \ln (N-n)] & = - \ln(N-n)-1
\end{align}$$

Using these three equations we have

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}[N \ln N - n \ln n - (N-n)\ln (N-n)]= \ln(N-n)-ln(n)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is correct. I believe you are solving for the maximum of $N \choose n$, and in the case, the approximation $\ln(x!) \approx x\ln(x)-x$ might be a bit cleaner, as after applying the derivative and product rule we get that 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x!) \approx\ln(x)$$

Comment: Thanks. Yep that's how I got $N \ln N - n \ln n - (N-n)\ln (N-n)$, using Stirling's approximation.

Comment: @PatrickMoloney Some intuition on the above approximation of the derivative may be found elementarily, noting that$$\ln(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k)\approx\int_1^n\ln(x)~\mathrm dx$$which has a derivative of $\ln(n)$.

Comment: that's beautiful.